# SSH only for onion network

Tags: onion-services, torsocks

https://medium.com/@tzhenghao/how-to-ssh-over-tor-onion-service-c6d06194147

I follow this tutorial, but I want that my ssh service only works in onion network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, just change your SSH configuration so it only binds to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0, so it can only be accessed by local processes.